# Asp.net Report Viewer - Custom filter parameters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

for a data warehouse project I need to know about some best practices regarding custom report viewer filters/parameters.

Usually I use the standard parameter feature for reports, like multiple select boxes, check boxes, text boxes etc.. But for the current project some reports require more complex report parameters. E.g. a user wants to analyze some measures. For that the user needs to set a filter on a specific address. There are over 100.000 address to choose from, so he has to have the ability to search for an address (full text). Since such features cannot be done with the standard parameters, I will have to create custom params within a ASPX page which are then passed to the report viewer control.

So my question is: Are there any best practices on how to create custom parameters? Did anyone had similar problems, if so, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your parameters on a simple web form that queries valid values from the database.  Then Pass the parameters to the report server via the URL.  Here is the documentation for Passing parameters via URL string

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835.aspx